# undefined method `update_attribute' for nil:NilClass, signing out

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have been stuck on this problem for a while, but still can't figure out what the problem is

```
def sign_out
 #return unless signed_in? # you are already signed out
 current_user.update_attribute(:remember_token,User.digest(User.new_remember_token))
 cookies.delete(:remember_token)
 self.current_user = nil
end
```

rails returns me a error on @current_user, saying the update attribute undefined?

As far as i understand, my current user is already defined by this method

```
def current_user
 remember_token = User.digest(cookies[:remember_token])
 current_user  ||= User.find_by(remember_token: remember_token)
end
```

Am i missing something here? I'm following the rails tutorials if it helps, but I kind of strayed off and added a additional page after the user creates a profile..... but I'm sure its ok because i saved the @user by doing

```
    User.find(params[:id])
```

Or can someone explain to me the error in better detail?

Thank you

Comment: try using `current_user.update_attribute` instead of `@current_user`

Comment: oops, that was a mistake. but even with current.user it still crashes

Comment: what if a user with the specified `remember_token` doesn't exist? `current_user` will return nil.

Comment: @sevenseacat i see your point, but does that mean my sign_in method is broken? following your logic, sign_in creates a remember_token when called... but i redirect the user to another page, shouldn't the token be saved?

Comment: Please, If your old question haven't no one answer and you want to create a new question with the same topic/problem you should delete your old question first http://stackoverflow.com/q/24050791/1297435. FYI [What should I do if no one answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/no-one-answers)

Answer (score 0):

The method `current_user` will define the `@current_user` instance variable, but this is for it's own purposes - to stop it having to do a db query every time it's called.

You can access `@current_user` in your own code, but it won't exist if `current_user` hasn't been called yet, and will therefore evaluate to nil.

It's therefore safer to always use `current_user` and never use `@current_user`.

Comment: ah sorry that was a mistake, i was trying things out and seeing if using @current would fix my problem. didnt and the orginal code is still actually current_user

Comment: ah.  you should update your question to take `@current_user` out then.

Answer (score 0):

> Can someone explain to me the error in better detail?

--

**current_user**

```
update_attribute' for nil:NilClass
```

This error is nothing to do with `update_attribute`, and *everything* to do with the object you're trying to call the method on - in your case `current_user` (basically means `current_user` is not defined)

The answers & comments you've been given basically are trying to help define the object you're calling the method on - I.E that `current_user` needs to be defined somewhere

---

From looking at your code, there are two things you need to consider:

> 1. Is `current_user` method being created / called?
> 2. Is the correct object being defined in this method?

--

**Data**

You've provided the following method:

```
def current_user
 remember_token = User.digest(cookies[:remember_token])
 current_user  ||= User.find_by(remember_token: remember_token)
end
```

As pointed out by `sevenseacat`, the first thing I would do is ensure you've got a user who can be located with the `remember_token`. An important point actually - **what's `.digest`?**. Is it a class method in your model?

The likely problem you've got is trying to use the `User.digest` and `User.find_by` with the `remember_token`. Do you know where / how the `remember_token` will be set?

--

**Method**

Secondly, you need to make sure you're calling the `current_user` method. I'm guessing this is a helper method? If so, are you sure you're calling `include xxxHelper` in your controller?

Answer (score 0):

never mind, found the bug.Had some unwanted code in my application controller